# Haskell, Measuring CPU time of a function

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I need to measure CPU time of a function like following:

```
t <- getCPUTime
res <- callTheFunction input
t' <- getCPUTime
print $ t' - t
```

The problem comes from the laziness of Haskell. callTheFunction must be strictly evaluated. I've searched a lot and tried to use seq and $! but without success. I think this should be a quite common task. Anyway, I need some help. Thanks.

**Update:**
Thanks for all the help, especially @FUZxxl. It reminds me the difference between WHNF (Weak Head Normal Form) and Normal Form. 
[Haskell/Laziness](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness)
helps understand the lazy evaluation of Haskell.

What I needed is one more step evaluation. Anyway $! or evaluate both works as long as only WHNF is needed for res:

```
t <- getCPUTime
res <- callTheFunction input
evaluate res  OR  return $! res
t' <- getCPUTime
print $ t' - t
```

Comment: This doesn't fix your strictness issue at all (use evaluate for that) but for the quick-and-dirty timings (i.e. simpler than criterion) you can just use the timeIt package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/timeit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the function `evaluate :: a -> IO a` from `Control.Exception`. It evaluates its argument  to WHNF when the corresponding IO-action is executed. You have to make sure that WHNF is sufficient for your function though.

Comment: Note that WHNF is often not sufficient.  As an example, WHNF of a list is only the first cons.

Comment: You could combine evaluate and enforcing than.

Answer (score 8):

If you're benchmarking then you should use [Criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).  Otherwise use [NFData](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/deepseq/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Control-DeepSeq.html#t%3aNFData) (rnf) and [bang patterns](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html) to force evaluation.

Comment: The problem is, that especially in an IO context, `seq`and `rnf` often aren't strong enough to eval the expression to the desired grade.

Comment: @FUZxxl I'm not clear on what you're getting at.  If you at any point (before or after the IO operation) have a value of type `NFData a => a` then bang patterns and `rnf` should be sufficient (certainly better than WHNF for many cases).

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to do benchmarks please use the excellent criterion  library, which is on Hackage.